# Category page not working Magento 2 with more than 13 million products

Tags: magento2, database, performance

I am stuck in an issue with Magento 2 has more than 13 million products. We have managed to upload 13 million products although is slow and it works like indexing, product page, and search page.
[image]

My frontend category page isn't opening now after waiting almost 2 minutes getting memory exhausted we have tried to allocate 18GB memory but it gets stuck on this query and through error memory exhausted.

> SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`sku`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id='4'
>    INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)

Can anyone please suggest me how can I overcome this issue or speed up the processes and MySQL queries what architecture level changes should I do to make it work the category list page on frontend. I know this is huge data but it's our requirement to have this much products. We have a pretty good server

- Intel Xeon E5-2689v4
- 128 GB RAM
- 1200 GB Datastores

Comment: Try to explain the query in MySQL to see what exactly it is trying to fetch. Strange for me is that it tries to load all products from category ID = 4. Probably there is huge number of products and php is not able to load all of them because of the memory limit. Try to debug it and see where and why it is called without any criteria.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: Please post TEXT RESULTS of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ....... (your query);  Thanks

Comment: No posting of requested data=No analysis to improve your instance.

Comment: No information=no suggestions.

Comment: Hi Wilson I actually fixed it with some customizations Thanks for your suggestions and reply

Comment: @OBAID If you could post the information requested, you will receive some AMAZING configuration Suggestions to improve response time.

Comment: @OBAID  If you could post the information requested, you will receive some AMAZING configuration Suggestions to improve response time. Offer is still OPEN.

Comment: @WilsonHauck we have actually fix it by doing some core changes and server-side cache.

Comment: @OBAID Very good, would you like improved response time?  Information requested Apr 26, 2019 will make it possible for your hosting server.